# Displaying an Array for a JavaScript/HTML project?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This is bulding off of a previous assignment, in which we coded a page where you can insert numbers and alert the user with buttons. You can also alert for number of elements entered, sum of numbers entered, etc. Here is the code for that:

```
<head><title>

CSE 1340 – Assignment 4, by Student
    <h1>Student Assignment 4</h1>
</title>
<script src = "javabuttonscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
"></link>
</head>

<body>

Output: <input type="text" id="num1" placeholder="Enter Number"></input>



<button id = "add" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add to List</button>
<button id = "numelements" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Num. Elements?</button>
<button id = "print" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print Sum</button>
<button id = "clear" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear List</button>
    <button id = "array" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Show Array</button>

</body>
    </html>

JavaScript Code:
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var numElements = document.getElementById("numelements");
var printButton = document.getElementById("print");
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
var nums = [];
add.addEventListener("click", function(){addFun();});
printButton.addEventListener("click",function(){print();});
numElements.addEventListener("click",function(){numElementsButton();});
clearButton.addEventListener("click",function(){clear();});
function print()
{
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
sum+=nums[i];
}
alert(sum);
}
function clear()
    {
if(nums.length ==0)
{
alert("already empty");
}
else
{
nums = [];
}
    }
function numElementsButton()
{
alert(nums.length);
}
function addFun()
    {
if(num1.value == "")
{
alert("Empty");
    }
    else if(isNaN(num1.value))
    {

alert("Not a valid number");
    }
else
    {
var number = parseInt(num1.value);
var addable = true;
for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
{
if(number == nums[i]){addable = false;}
    }
if(addable)
    {
nums.push(number);
}
else
{
alert("Number already on list");
        }
    }
}
```

Then here are the directions for the rest of the project! Thank you so much!

Add a button named ‘Show Array’ which will show the current contents of the array

3. Create a button named ‘Toggle Order’ (styled via Bootstrap)such that it toggles the order in which the array is sorted.
   By default the array issorted in ascending order. For example, given the numbers 1, 50 and 5, the array sort order is
   1, 5, 50. If the User clicks the button, then the order will be 50, 5, 1, i.e., descending order. And if the button is clicked
   again, then the array is sorted in ascendingorder, i.e., 1, 5, 50 and so on. Thus, whenever the button is clicked, the
   array is re-sorted and the sort order is reversed from whatever it is right now. You must implement your own version
   of a Sort (we discuss Bubble sort in class, but it is up to you what kind of sort you implement). You cannot rely on the
   default .sort function provided by JavaScript.
4. Update your program such that whenever the User adds a new number it is inserted in the right place per the current
   sort order. For example, if the sort order is currently ascending and the array is 1, 5, 10, then when the User inserts a
   new number – say 6, then the resulting array should be 1, 5, 6, 10. Conversely, if the array is 10, 5, 1 and the User
   inserts 6, then the resulting array should be 10, 6, 5, 1.

Comment: What's your question? :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. However, please note that it is not a do-my-homework-for-me site. You need to define what specific problem you are facing, and what is stopping you from resolving it. If you just need code done for you, and don't need to learn anything, go hire a developer.

Comment: Homework ? :P atleast remove that line :P

Comment: I don't know how to show the contents of the array. So I guess that would be my first question @matt. Second, I don't know what the toggle button is. I have done some research and this is what I came up with: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">
    Single toggle
</button>

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I really should learn to reload the comments before posting, sorry folks!

Comment: @Amadan I am trying to learn how to do it. Maybe I should have asked in a different manner, but how can I learn how to do it if I don't ask what I need to learn?

Comment: You did not ask how to do it, you dumped the assignment on us. That is a very different matter. "How to display contents of an array" is a good question, if basic, since it shows a specific problem (you'd then be asked if you want to display in console, or on page; and whether you want it in a list, for example, or as a JS literal; it would be best to show an example of HTML that contains the displayed array, as an example of what you want). "What is a toggle button" is explicitly explained in your #4, so you would need to explain which specific place you didn't understand for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the sorting part you might be interested in extending the `Array` object. With the proposed "Bubble Sort" (please don't use it, use e.g.: merge-sort or, if you understood how it works, quick-sort)

```
Array.prototype.bubblesort = function(down) {
  var tmp;
  // we work on copy here
  var a = this.slice(0);

  for (var i = a.length; i > 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (down) {
        if (a[j] < a[j + 1]) {
          tmp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j + 1];
          a[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
      } else {
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
          tmp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j + 1];
          a[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

If you want to make your life simple at the cost of a small heap of CPU cycles you can memorize the sorting direction somewhere (or, with a handful more CPU cycles, test it), `push` the additional element and sort the resulting, elongated array in the right direction afterwards.

But that's not what your teacher intended. You take your element and put it in the correct position in the array directly. You can do it with [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) quite easily if you found the correct place to insert the new element. Yes, you still need to either memorize the sorting direction somewhere or test for it.

Sounds like a lot to do but it shouldn't make you more headaches than necessary.

Comment: Would this go below the "alert("Number already on list");" ??

Comment: also, why is the function "(down)", and I have no idea what "tmp" is. Do you mind explaining? Thank you so much!

Comment: If this is your fourth assignment, how did you solve the last three? `tmp` is the temporary variable we need when we swap the elements in the array while bubble-sorting. `down` is the argument to the function that sorts in descending order if set to `true`. If you missed the first lessons because you were sick of whatever: pleeeeease read your text-book! You're lacking the basics and will fail miserably and/or immediately if you don't. If you can't afford a good text-book see e.g.: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ it's free.

Comment: [What is `tmp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_\(computer_science\)). [Explanation of Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).